# Can we read iPhone messages programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

Can we read iPhone messages programmatically like we can do in android? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cant read the messages an iPhone receives, Apple doesn't allow it.
There are no public APIs for this.